# Nest can't resolve dependencies of the TrackerService (?)

Tags: typescript, nestjs

Err: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the TrackerService (?). Please make sure that the argument DriverModel at index [0] is available in the AppModule context.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yl8Bi.png)
Potential solutions:

- If DriverModel is a provider, is it part of the current AppModule?
- If DriverModel is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within AppModule?
  @Module({
  imports: [ /* the Module containing DriverModel */ ]

```
app.module

import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { AppGateway } from './app.gateway';
import { TrackerModule } from './tracker/tracker.module';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';

@Module({
  imports: [TrackerModule,MongooseModule.forRoot('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/tracker')],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppGateway,AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
'

tracker.module

import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TrackerService } from './tracker.service';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { DriverSchema } from './schemas/driver.schema';

@Module({
  imports: [MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name :'Driver', schema: DriverSchema }])],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [TrackerService]
})
export class TrackerModule {}


tracker.service

import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Driver } from './interfaces/driver.interface';
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
import { driverDto } from './dtos/driver.dto';

@Injectable()
export class TrackerService {
    
    constructor(@InjectModel('Driver') private driverModel: Model<Driver>){}

    addDriver( driverDTO: driverDto): Promise<Driver>{
    const newDriver = new this.driverModel(driverDTO);
    return newDriver.save();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you be a bit specific on where do you need help here?

Comment: i can't figure out where my problem is, I've registered all my providers in their corresponding modules and imported the modules in app.module. but when i run the app i end up in that error.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have `TrackerService` added to the `providers` array of `AppModule`. Seeing as this provider is already in the `providers` array of `TrackerModule` you don't need to add it anywhere else. If you would like to use it elsewhere, it should be added to the `exports` of `TrackerModule` and then `TrackerModule` should be added to the `imports` of the array you want to use `TrackerService` in.

Comment: as you can see in the code, i only added the tracker service in corresponding tracker module exports array, and imported the tracker module in app.module. didn't mentioned tracker service in app.module or anywhere else.

Comment: I misread the error too quickly. You have `DriverModel` in an imports of `AppModule`